# Was Teresa the manager or not in "Dead End Girl"?

Tags: meaning, dead-end-girl, tim-mcbain, l-t-vargus

The prologue of *Dead End Girl*, narrates the experience of Teresa Riley finding a body in the oil dumpster at the Burger King she works at. At one point in the narration we find the following statement:

> She’d wanted to institute random drug testing, but the store manager wouldn’t allow it. Something about the Constitution. Whatever.

This indicates that she was not the store manager. In Chapter Three, however, Teresa is described as the Burger King manager:

> How long had she been in the oil? Darger squinted, trying to remember the interview notes with Teresa Riley, the Burger King manager. The one who had found the body.

Are “store manager” and “Burger King manager” different things? If so, what is the difference? If not, how are we to resolve this apparent contradiction?